# GA4 | How can we merge 2 GA4 accounts or Move all the collected events form one to another?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-sdk

Google Analytics: How can we merge 2 GA4 accounts or Move all the collected events from one to another?

Already Tried:

Data Import > Offline Event Import:

Here, I've created a custom CSV per the official schema provided by the analytics team. While uploading the file, the progress percentage is stuck at 0% and gets refreshed after a few seconds. Observed 500 status code in the network tab.

Tried to report the same to Google Analytics support. Unfortunately, there is no direct contact with the product team. Hence, I am seeking help here. How to go about it?

Comment: you cant data import isnt the same structure